# Django Noob URL to from Root Page to sub Page

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Django project where I want to use an app for all the sites web pages. My project looks like this:

```
project
  src
    project
      urls.py
      views.py
      ...
    web
      migrations #package
      urls.py
      views.py
      ...
      templates
        web
          index.html # I want this to be my root page
          page2.html # This is the second page I'm trying to link to
```

I am trying to create a link in `index.html` that will take me to `page2.html`. This is what I am doing

In `project->urls.py` I have `url(r'^$', include('web.urls', namespace="web")),`. This should direct all page requests going to url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to page `index.html`

`project->views.py` is empty because I want all web pages served up by the `web` app.

In `web->urls.py` I have `url(r'^$', views.index, name='home_page')` which relates to `web->views.py` and the function

```
def index(request):
   print("Main index Page")
   return render(request, 'web/index.html', {})
```

Which returns the correct page.

This works fine until I add the link to `index.html` for `page2.html`. The link looks like this: `{% url 'web:page2' %}`. I update `web->urls.py`. I add the following function into `web->views.py`:

```
def page2(request):
   print("Page2")
   return render(request, 'web/page2.html', {})
```

Now I get

```
Reverse for 'page2' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$page2/?$']
```

With the '{% url 'web:page2' %}' line highlighted.

When I remove the link everything works fine. What is wrong with my logic/setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an additional URL pattern:

```
urls = [
    url(r'^page2/$', views.page2, name='page2'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='home_page'),
]
```

or alternatively, pass a parameter you can use to identify the page to be rendered to the view. Currently, you aren't mapping a URL to the function you want to call when the URL is matched for page2, just the home page.